# Multiple Prototype Cells into UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I want to have a TableView with multiple Prototype Cells. I've found some solutions online, but they have have too much repetitive code, especially as my system scales. How can I write a solution that works like [Similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993496/load-multiple-prototype-cells-into-uitableview) but that defines a cell outside of the switch or conditional statements?

This is the working code from the solution:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let cell: FlightsDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FlightsDetailCell
    cell.graphView.enableBezierCurve = true
    cell.graphView.enableReferenceYAxisLines = true
    cell.graphView.enableYAxisLabel = true
    cell.graphView.colorYaxisLabel = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.graphView.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as BEMSimpleLineGraphDelegate
    cell.graphView.dataSource = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as BEMSimpleLineGraphDataSource
    return cell
}

else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    let cell: FlightsDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FlightsDetailCell
    cell.graphView.enableBezierCurve = true
    cell.graphView.enableReferenceYAxisLines = true
    cell.graphView.enableYAxisLabel = true
    cell.graphView.colorYaxisLabel = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.graphView.delegate = self
    cell.graphView.dataSource = self
    return cell
}    

else {
    let cell2: FlightsInformationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FlightsInformationCell
    cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
    return cell2
}
```

I want a solution that looks like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    switch (variable){
        case "1":
            cellIdentifier = "Identifier"
            cell = cell as! MyTableViewCell
        case "2":
            cellIdentifier = "anotherIdentifier"
            cell = cell as! MyOtherTableViewCell
    }
    cell.a.text = "hello"
    cell.b.text = "hello"
    ...
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can't have completely above code under a `switch` case because there are not all the things common defines for particular cell. But, yeah, you can simply the code in this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell: AnyObject?

switch(indexPath.section){

    case 0:

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlightsDetailCell
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.graphView.enableBezierCurve = true
        cell.graphView.enableReferenceYAxisLines = true
        cell.graphView.enableYAxisLabel = true
        cell.graphView.colorYaxisLabel = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.graphView.delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as BEMSimpleLineGraphDelegate
        cell.graphView.dataSource = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as BEMSimpleLineGraphDataSource    

    case 1:

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlightsDetailCell
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.graphView.enableBezierCurve = true
        cell.graphView.enableReferenceYAxisLines = true
        cell.graphView.enableYAxisLabel = true
        cell.graphView.colorYaxisLabel = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.graphView.delegate = self
        cell.graphView.dataSource = self

    default:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlightsInformationCell
        ce.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps!